# Does Appcelerator Titanium (desktop) work with Flash/Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, flash, appcelerator

> http://www.appcelerator.com/2009/06/titanium-beta/
>
> In addition to supporting traditional Web technologies such as HTML, CSS and JavaScript, Titanium supports applications developed using Adobe Flash, Microsoft Silverlight, or any third-party AJAX library, on Mac OS, Windows, Linux, Android or iPhone platforms.

While the Appcelerator forums contain several issues concerning Flash, I haven't found anything in the API docs. So,

- How would I integrate Flash/Silverlight in my Titanium app?
- Any limitations?
- Does it use any present browser plug-ins on the user's machine?
- Cross-OS compliance? (Silverlight on iPhone!?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this answer will depend on the platform.  But I know on the iPad / iPhone you can call up webpages in essentially an embedded browser. You can also show PDFs this way and other things.  This uses Safari on the iPhone / iPad.  Since it's on the mobile device Flash / Silverlight won't work since it needs plugins.

However, I would think on the desktop where you could install Silverlight and Flash that it's very possible to use the web browser within Titanium to load an HTML file that contains your Flash or Silverlight embed.  This would then display it within your application.

I've not done this as I just use Titanium for mobile, but seems like it would work for desktop.

Comment: After trying out, I can confirm that Flash works for Titanium Desktop, if it is installed. However, it crashes when the context menu "Info" entry is selected.